# How can I set the Java heap size for elasticsearch on Nixos?

Tags: java, nixos, nix, elasticsearch

It seems these should go in the `${configDir}/jvm.options"}` (`/var/lib/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options` ?) looking at the package at https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/services/search/elasticsearch.nix

Possibly I could use the `ES_JAVA_OPTS` environment variable?

Using `services.elasticsearch.extraJavaOptions` does not work as it seems something is passing `-Xms1g -Xmx1g` by default:

Output from `ps aux`

> elastic+ 21271 30.8 47.5 4456956 950968 ?      Ssl  01:03   3:41
>   /nix/store/9c5a9fq2vd6qah77nmg87sjq5wbss1kj-openjdk-8u212-ga-jre/bin/java
>   -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.uQNUAfPs -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=data -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:logs/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32 -XX:GCLogFileSize=64m -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Des.path.home=/var/lib/elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=/var/lib/elasticsearch/config -Des.distribution.flavor=default -Des.distribution.type=tar -cp /var/lib/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch

Comment: Have you seen this, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html ? It is the first reference found by  Googling *elastisearch heap size*. It contains the full answer to your question, including using an environment variable.

Comment: I have - the difficulty is knowing how to integrate this ENVS / config with Nixos.

Comment: The `jvm.options` file is copied from the Nix store to `/var/lib/elasticsearch/config/` every time ElasticSearch is started. Hence changes to the file would get overwritten. Assuming `ES_JAVA_OPTS` takes precedence over `jvm.options`, you can do something like `services.elasticsearch.extraJavaOptions = [ "-Xms2g" "-Xmx2g" ]`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit overkill but I'm not too sure how to override a Nixos service's parameters.

Essentially the default options are in `.../jvm.options` so I copied the elasticsearch.nix from Github and modified the following:

```
        ${optionalString es6 "sed -i '/-Xms1g/d' ${configDir}/jvm.options"}
        ${optionalString es6 "sed -i '/-Xmx1g/d' ${configDir}/jvm.options"}
```

Along with **changing the name of the service** (otherwise I'd assume it would conflict). I then just included this nix expression into my config and it seems to be working with the appropriate values set in `ES_JAVA_OPTS`.